# express.js form post req.body is empty body {}

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following reactjs code and using expressjs to handle the post request. req.body always returns {} from the app. But it works in Postman.

my reactjs code snippet:

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(config.urlDev + '/notes', {
      method: 'post',
      body: { "email":"test" },
      //headers: {'Content-Type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

my expressjs code snippet:

```
module.exports = function (app, db) {

  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body)
     console.log(req.params)
     res.send(req.body)
  })
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.use(cors())
//app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

MongoClient.connect(db.url, {useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)

  const mydb = database.db('notes')

  require('./app/routes') (app, mydb);
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log ("server on " + port)
  })
})
```

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX5gt.png)

Comment: You're using the `bodyParser.urlencoded` parser, but you're trying to send JSON. Perhaps you meant to use `bodyParser.json()` which you've commented out, and meant to stringify the payload: `body: JSON.stringify({ "email": "test" })`

Comment: @cbr That worked. So help me to understand further. What if I want to send a JSON object instead of a string?

Comment: You are sending the JSON object. It just needs to be transformed into a string because the HTTP body is sent as a string. The `bodyParser.json()` middleware transforms the string from the HTTP body back into a JSON object, if the `Content-Type` matches `application/json`.

Comment: Just to be clear, a string is not the only type `fetch` accepts into the `body` property of its options, you can pass any of the following [according to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body): ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob/File, string, URLSearchParams, FormData.

Comment: Got it. But if I want to send a JSON object, then in my server.js, I should not include `app.use(bodyParser.json())` correct? In this case, I still get an empty req.body.

Comment: What do you mean by "send a JSON object"? Do you mean you want to "send a javascript object"? As in: `body: { "email": "foo" }`? Then the answer is that the way to do it is to use `bodyParser.json()` and `JSON.stringify` it before you put it in the fetch body - by doing that you are *sending the object*. You are sending the object, it just just temporarily turned into a JSON string so that it can be sent over HTTP! It is turned back into your "JSON object" when the server's bodyparser middleware parses it!

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try un-commenting the line
`//app.use(bodyParser.json())` and it should work.

or alternatively if you are sending headers in the fetch request as `headers: {'Content-Type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'}` instead of `headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}` it should work.

Comment: if i add `headers: {'Content-Type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'}`, should i leave `app.use(bodyParser.json())` commented? I still get an empty req.body in this case.

Comment: did you comment `headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}`

Comment: Bodyparser's `.urlencoded()` middleware checks for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. Bodyparser's `.json()` checks for `Content-Type: application/json`. If those headers are not present, the middleware does not do anything to the body.

Comment: @at07 yes, I commented it out.

Comment: no changes in the server side code and react code should look like: `  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(config.urlDev + '/notes', {
      method: 'post',
      body: { "email":"test" },
      headers: {'Content-Type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }`